# django - how to override a form textbox widget with a string?

Tags: django, django-templates

Still fairly new to django and python...

I've defined two forms as follows:

```
 class PasswordForm(forms.Form):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.name={'label':'Name', 'data':''}

     def get_name(self):
         return self.name['data']

     def set_name(self, name):
         self.name['data'] = name

     name = property(get_name, set_name)

     pass1 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
     pass2 = forms.CharField(max_length=20)


 class UserForm(PasswordForm):
     name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

The reason I've set it up like this is as follows:

- trying to use a single template to handle both forms
- sometimes only want to validate PasswordForm fields, other times both UserForm AND PasswordForm fields, hence two forms
- in the template, sometimes want to display name as a textbox input, and other times as just a string showing the value of name (i.e. uneditable)

I thought I would be able to loop over something like the following in the template

```
 {{ form.field.label }} {{ form.field }}
```

What ends up happening is that the development server crashes (i.e. 'python manage.py runserver') hard - no error messages, just quits.

Obviously, I've done something wrong, but don't know what. Is it possible to override the textbox input with a string in such a way that the template is none the wiser? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Thanks for your help!

W.

**EDIT:**
As per Pasty Legs' answer, the thing to do is to override the widget used. A couple of tweaks to the syntax in widgets.py for it to work for me:

```
 from django.forms import widgets                                                                         
 from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe 

 class StringWidget(widgets.Input):                                                                       
     def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):                                                           
         # Create a hidden field first                                                                    
         hidden_field = widgets.HiddenInput(attrs)                                                        
         return mark_safe(u'%s %s' % (value, hidden_field.render(value, attrs)))
```

Comment: can you post your view.py code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use a disabled input instead of trying to replace it?

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/disabled

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    apple = models.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}))
```

If you need to dynamically decide whether or not to set the input as disabled (as opposed to above where it is always disabled) you can overwrite the constructur

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    apple = models.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if something:
            self.fields['apple'].widget.attrs["disabled"] = 'disabled'
```

---

**EDIT**
To get the field to display as a string, you will need to override the widget (i.e. the HTML used to display that form field). The problem is that if you don't include the text in some sort of form element, it will get lost on form submission. The easiest way to get around this is to create a custom widget that displays the string and the string as a hidden input text field:

Create a widgets.py:

```
from django.forms import widgets
class StringWidget(widgets.Input):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        # Create a hidden field first
        hidden_field = widgets.HiddenField(attrs) 
        return mark_safe(u'<p>%s</p>%s' % (value, hidden_field.render(value, attrs))
```

forms.py

```
from myapp.widgets import StringWidget
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    apple = models.CharField(widget=StringWidget())
```

This will produce something like the following in your template when you loop over it:

```
<p>granny smith</p>
<input type="hidden" class="..." name="id_apple" value="granny smith" />
```

i.e. the user will be able to see, but not edit it.

Comment: Thanks! Testing this, it certainly does approximately what I want. The disabled field still appears as a text box however, and I would prefer a simple string.  Is there no Python syntax to override the field? That way, I can pass the appropriate form to the template; that seems to be a more 'object oriented' way of doing things...

Comment: Thanks again! I had to make a couple changes to the syntax to make it work for me, but work it does!

Comment: Very clever - essentially override the widget, not the field type.